# One <span> per character in web-based text editor

Tags: javascript, dom, text, editor, element

I'm developing a web-based text editor without any `contentEditable`, `textarea` or `input` things. The biggest portion of my work is to measure widths of text on the left (right) side from the current *caret* position and moving the caret in the text.

For example when user presse the DOWN key a current left-offset of the caret must be computed and on the line below a character which's position is most similar must be found.

One very convenient way to do is to use one DOM element per character - I can just look at the `offsetLeft` property. Also, positioning the caret is much easier. Actually, everything is easier.

However **I'm very unsure about the performance implications**. I have seen this technique (or similar) used on some web-based JavaScript "IDE"s and it works just fine there.

Do you have any hints, tips?

Do you know some other fast way how to measure width of text. I want to avoid putting sections of a line to a DOM element and measuring its width each time as I think it will be much slower.

EDIT: I'm mostly asking about the main fact of EXISTENCE of many dom elements. How to do the measuring is a different thing.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this done (unfortunately can't find the link now) by using a canvas object and its measureText() method - basically you can ask a canvas "what size would this piece of text be if i rendered it in this style?" and use that to determine your caret position on the surrounding lines. This is performant, but of course it will only work in HTML5-capable browsers, and maybe not all of them.

But frankly this sounds like a big pain in the neck and probably more trouble than it's worth for an in-browser editor :)

Comment: But it sill sound as much less pain than measureDiv.clientWidth . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [this](http://gpl.internetconnection.net/vi/), which is a javascript implementation of the VI text editor. Unfortunately it does use a textarea, however not in the typical manner.

Comment: While that is interesting, the problem described does not really exist for jsvi, simply because it uses monospace fonts. You wouldn't need to calculate the x-position of the caret when moving up or down because it wouldn't change.

Comment: I'm mostly asking about the main fact of EXISTENCE of many dom elements. How to do the measuring is a different thing.